# Why does AWS SAM CLI 1.33.0 crash with _regex.cpython-38-darwin.so no suitable image found on Apple M1 chips?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

Today I updated to `AWS SAM CLI` version 1.33.0. Then it started crashing making issues during the deployment. When I run the command `sam deploy` or `sam deploy --guided`, it throws the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/bin/sam", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/cli_validation/image_repository_validation.py", line 85, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 153, in wrapped
    raise exception  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 122, in wrapped
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/utils/version_checker.py", line 42, in wrapped
    actual_result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/cli/main.py", line 90, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/commands/deploy/command.py", line 216, in cli
    do_cli(
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/commands/deploy/command.py", line 280, in do_cli
    from samcli.commands.deploy.deploy_context import DeployContext
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/commands/deploy/deploy_context.py", line 32, in <module>
    from samcli.lib.deploy.deployer import Deployer
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/deploy/deployer.py", line 39, in <module>
    from samcli.lib.utils.time import utc_to_timestamp
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/utils/time.py", line 6, in <module>
    import dateparser
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateparser/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .date import DateDataParser
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateparser/date.py", line 6, in <module>
    import regex as re
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/regex/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .regex import *
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/regex/regex.py", line 419, in <module>
    import regex._regex_core as _regex_core
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/regex/_regex_core.py", line 21, in <module>
    import regex._regex as _regex
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/regex/_regex.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/regex/_regex.cpython-38-darwin.so: code signature in (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/regex/_regex.cpython-38-darwin.so) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: Trying to load an unsigned library
yohanweerasinghe@Yohans-MacBook-Pro amazon-s3-presigned-urls-aws-sam % sam deploy --guided
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/bin/sam", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/cli_validation/image_repository_validation.py", line 85, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 153, in wrapped
    raise exception  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 122, in wrapped
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/utils/version_checker.py", line 42, in wrapped
    actual_result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/cli/main.py", line 90, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/commands/deploy/command.py", line 216, in cli
    do_cli(
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/commands/deploy/command.py", line 280, in do_cli
    from samcli.commands.deploy.deploy_context import DeployContext
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/commands/deploy/deploy_context.py", line 32, in <module>
    from samcli.lib.deploy.deployer import Deployer
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/deploy/deployer.py", line 39, in <module>
    from samcli.lib.utils.time import utc_to_timestamp
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/utils/time.py", line 6, in <module>
    import dateparser
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateparser/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .date import DateDataParser
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateparser/date.py", line 6, in <module>
    import regex as re
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/regex/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
yohanweerasinghe@Yohans-MacBook-Pro amazon-s3-presigned-urls-aws-sam % sam deploy --guided
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/bin/sam", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/cli_validation/image_repository_validation.py", line 85, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 153, in wrapped
    raise exception  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 122, in wrapped
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/utils/version_checker.py", line 42, in wrapped
    actual_result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/cli/main.py", line 90, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/commands/deploy/command.py", line 216, in cli
    do_cli(
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/commands/deploy/command.py", line 280, in do_cli
    from samcli.commands.deploy.deploy_context import DeployContext
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/commands/deploy/deploy_context.py", line 32, in <module>
    from samcli.lib.deploy.deployer import Deployer
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/deploy/deployer.py", line 39, in <module>
    from samcli.lib.utils.time import utc_to_timestamp
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/utils/time.py", line 6, in <module>
    import dateparser
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateparser/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .date import DateDataParser
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateparser/date.py", line 6, in <module>
    import regex as re
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/regex/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
yohanweerasinghe@Yohans-MacBook-Pro amazon-s3-presigned-urls-aws-sam % sam deploy --guided
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/bin/sam", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/cli_validation/image_repository_validation.py", line 85, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 153, in wrapped
    raise exception  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 122, in wrapped
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/utils/version_checker.py", line 42, in wrapped
    actual_result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/cli/main.py", line 90, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/commands/deploy/command.py", line 216, in cli
    do_cli(
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/commands/deploy/command.py", line 280, in do_cli
    from samcli.commands.deploy.deploy_context import DeployContext
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/commands/deploy/deploy_context.py", line 32, in <module>
    from samcli.lib.deploy.deployer import Deployer
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/deploy/deployer.py", line 39, in <module>
    from samcli.lib.utils.time import utc_to_timestamp
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/utils/time.py", line 6, in <module>
    import dateparser
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateparser/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .date import DateDataParser
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateparser/date.py", line 6, in <module>
    import regex as re
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/regex/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .regex import *
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/regex/regex.py", line 419, in <module>
    import regex._regex_core as _regex_core
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/regex/_regex_core.py", line 21, in <module>
    import regex._regex as _regex
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/regex/_regex.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/regex/_regex.cpython-38-darwin.so: code signature in (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/regex/_regex.cpython-38-darwin.so) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: Trying to load an unsigned library
```

I am on MacOS Big Sir 11.6, M1 Chip pro.

How can I fix this issue? Or possibly revert back to the former version of SAM?

**UPDATE**

This is the output for the command `brew info aws-sam-cli`

```
aws/tap/aws-sam-cli: stable 1.33.0, HEAD
AWS SAM CLI  is a tool for local development and testing of Serverless applications
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/
Conflicts with:
  aws-sam-cli-rc (because both install the 'sam' binary)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0 (5,872 files, 108.7MB) *
  Built from source on 2021-10-16 at 13:50:40
From: https://github.com/aws/homebrew-tap/blob/HEAD/Formula/aws-sam-cli.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: python@3.8 ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
```

Please check below the output for `brew search aws-sam-cli` command

```
==> Formulae
aws/tap/aws-sam-cli ✔                    aws/tap/aws-sam-cli-nightly
aws/tap/aws-sam-cli-beta-acc             aws/tap/aws-sam-cli-rc
aws/tap/aws-sam-cli-beta-cdk             aws-sam-cli-rc
```

Comment: What commands did you exactly run PeakGen?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary: Thank you for the reply. I am on MacOS Big Sur 11.6, M1 Chip Pro. To upgrade I did `brew upgrade aws-sam-cli`. Then to build I did `sam build`. Then to deploy I tries `sam deploy` and `sam deploy --guided` and both generated the error.

Comment: I'd search through open/closed issues at the SAM github issues site.

Comment: @jarmod: I did a small search, could not find anything. May be go back to the former version is possible?

Comment: What version were you on?

Comment: Actually, can you please give me the output of `brew info aws-sam-cli`? You may already have the old one installed

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary: sure. Please check the updates answer.

Comment: Ah you don't have it installed - do you know the version that was working?

Comment: `brew search aws-sam-cli` may give your memory a hint :)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary: errr. I dont know. But I can guarantee whatever the former version was the immediate version before the current one. Because I always update.

Comment: Output of `brew search aws-sam-cli`? Sorry I'm on Windows atm or I'd check myself

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary: sure. Please check the updated question.

Comment: Ah, crap - try `pip3 install --user 'aws-sam-cli==1.30.0'` and see if that works - if not, try `pip3 install --user 'aws-sam-cli==1.20.0'`

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary: Sure, let me try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238218/discussion-between-ermiya-eskandary-and-peakgen).

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary: Thank you a lot for all the support you have provided, really appreciate that. I created an issue in github and AWS team responded. The issue is with the regex in Apple M1, AWS team will fix this. Until then, there is a workaround. Please check the below answer given by a senior developer at AWS SAM team.

Comment: As we figured! Glad you got it sorted :)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary: ☺️☺️☺️☺️☺️☺️☺️☺️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have identified the issue and a fix is on the way. The issue is a version of regex. We need to pin to a specific version (2021.9.30) as later ones are having issues on M1. A new version of the CLI will address this.

For now, the workarounds are

1. For brew installs: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/bin/pip3 install regex==2021.9.30`
2. For PIP installs: `pip install regex==2021.9.30`

Answer (score 0):

You can sign the regex.so by `codesign`:

```
xcrun codesign --sign - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.33.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/regex/_regex.cpython-38-darwin.so
```